# Return the anagram of the first word that has appeared in the second word.

Tags: java, algorithm

Given two words, determine if the first word, or any anagram of it, appears in consecutive characters of the second word. For instance, `tea` appears as an anagram in the last three letters of `slate`, but `let` does not appear as an anagram in `slate` even though all the letters of let appear in slate.
Return the anagram of the first word that has appeared in the second word.

```
Sample Input 1
tea
slate

Sample Output1
ate
Sample Input 2
let
slate

Sample Output2
NONE
```

I tried below got struck

```
public static boolean testAnagram(String originalWord, String containedWord)
{
char [] first = originalWord.toCharArray();//Get the first word and store it into a character array.
char [] second = containedWord.toCharArray();//Get the second word and store it into a character array.
int [] index = new int[second.length];//An int array that stores the index of matching letters contained in the original array.
int counter = 0;//Keep count of the index storage position.

//Compare each character of both words.

for(int i = 0; i < second.length; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < first.length; j++)
  {
    if(second[i] == first[j])
    {
      index[counter] = j; //Store matching letters.
      counter++; //Increment the index storage position.
      break;//Break for loop.
    }
  }
}

if(counter < second.length)return false;//If not all letters were found.

//get the distance between the indices which should be no more than one
//less than the contained word length (to qualify as an anagram)

for(int i = 0; i < index.length; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j = second.length) 
  {
    //stuck here
    return ;
  }
}

//If all qualifications are met.
return ;
}
```

Comment: Should it be "valid" words, or just any combination?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you do the following:

1. Iterate through each character in the second word (ex. slate)
2. When you find a character contained in the first word, get the substring that begins at this character with the length of the first word.
3. Check if this substring is an anagram of the first word.

   ```
    String getSubAnagram (String s1, String s2){
           for (int i = 0; i = s1.length(); i++) {
               if(s1.indexOf(s2.charAt(i)) >-1){
                   if(isAnagram(s1, s2.substring(i, s1.length()+i)))
                       return s2.substring(i, s1.length()+i);
               }
           }
           return null;
    }
   ```

Comment: What will be the complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Use a forward-test for each next character in the shorter word, starting at each character in the longer word. To prevent double matches, erase the matching character in a copy of the longer word.

As soon as the *next* character in the **longer** word is not in the **shorter** word, you know there is no use in continuing.

The following is in ANSI C, so you need to adjust the string functions to Java equivalents. The `compareForward` function modifies the shorter word to prevent double matches -- it overwrites the original character with a space -- and so you need to make sure it runs on a *copy* of the input word. (I'm not sure if Java does so automatically.)

This needs sort of O(n*(m-n)) comparisons. (Note that the *longer* word only needs checking until a *shorter* word length remains; hence the `strlen` end condition in the for loop in my `main`.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int compareForward (char *start, char *findThis)
{
    char *copyOfFind, *comparePos, *ptr;
    int loopCounter;

    printf ("is '%c' in '%s' to begin with?\n", *start, findThis);
    if (!strchr (findThis, *start))
    {
        printf ("first character not in shorter word, no use in continuing\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf (">\n");
    /* C needs a copy because you'll modify the original word otherwise */
    copyOfFind = strdup (findThis);
    comparePos = start;
    for (loopCounter=0; loopCounter < strlen(findThis); loopCounter++)
    {
        printf ("looking for '%c' in '%s'\n", *comparePos, copyOfFind);
        ptr = strchr (copyOfFind, *comparePos);
        if (!ptr)
        {
            printf ("not found, no use in continuing\n");
            break;
        }
        *ptr = ' ';
        comparePos++;
    }
    printf ("<\n");
    free (copyOfFind);

    /* Did we find all characters? */
    return loopCounter == strlen(findThis);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int loopy, match;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf ("invalid number of arguments\n");
        return 0;
    }

    match = -1;
    for (loopy=0; loopy < strlen(argv[2])-strlen(argv[1])+1; loopy++)
    {
        printf ("start at %s\n", argv[2]+loopy);
        if (compareForward (argv[2]+loopy, argv[1]))
        {
            match = loopy;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (match >= 0)
    {
        printf ("match at pos %d: ", match);
        for (loopy=0; loopy<strlen(argv[1]); loopy++)
            printf ("%c", argv[2][match+loopy]);
        printf ("\n");
    } else
        printf ("NONE\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static String isSubstringAnagram(String inp, String word) {
        int inpLen = inp.length(), wordLen = word.length();

        if (inpLen > wordLen) return "NONE";

        Set<Character> hs = new HashSet<>();
        for (char c : inp.toCharArray()) hs.add(c);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < wordLen - inpLen + 1; i++) {
            if (hs.contains(word.charAt(i))) {
                boolean flag = isAnagram(inp, word, i, inpLen);
                if (flag) return word.substring(i, i + inpLen);
            }
        }

        return "NONE";
    }

    private static boolean isAnagram(String inp, String word, int idx, int len) {
        int[] map = new int[26];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            map[inp.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
            map[word.charAt(i + idx) - 'a']--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            if (map[i] != 0)
                return false;
        
        return true;
    }
```